# formatting JTable with Grids java

Tags: java, swing, layout, jtable, gridbaglayout

I am having trouble moving my `JTable` around as well as making the rows width long enough to view all the data being displayed in them.

When I try and move the `JTable` it stays close to the other fields no matter what `grid` I change it to.

How can I make the table's rows wider so the data can be displayed properly as well as position the JTable to the top left of screen.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.sql.*;

import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

public class Driver {

    private JFrame f;

    private JPanel p;

    private JTextField fieldBN;
    private JTextField fieldFN;
    private JTextField fieldLN;
    private JTextField fieldP;
    private JTextField fieldE;
    private JTextField fieldA;
    private JTextField aLine2;
    private JTextField fieldW;

    private JLabel labelBN;
    private JLabel labelFN;
    private JLabel labelLN;
    private JLabel labelP;
    private JLabel labelE;
    private JLabel labelA;
    private JLabel labelW;

    private JComboBox relationship;

    private JButton buttonS;

    private JTable tableDisplay;

    String[] relationshipValues = { "Business", "Friend", "Family", "Professional" };

    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;

    // Constructor:

    public Driver() {       
        gui();      
        conn = DbConnect.ConnectDb();
        UpdateTable();
    }

    public void gui() { 
        f = new JFrame("Contact Book");


        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();  

        p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        f.getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    labelBN = new JLabel ("Business Name:");
    p.add(labelBN, c);  

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    fieldBN = new JTextField(10);
    p.add(fieldBN, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    labelFN= new JLabel ("First Name:");
    p.add(labelFN, c);      

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    fieldFN = new JTextField (10);
    p.add(fieldFN, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    labelLN= new JLabel ("Last Name:");
    p.add(labelLN, c);      

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 2;
    fieldLN = new JTextField (10);
    p.add(fieldLN, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 3;
    labelP = new JLabel ("Phone Number:");
    p.add(labelP, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 3;
    fieldP = new JTextField (10);
    p.add(fieldP, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 4;
    labelE = new JLabel ("Email:");
    p.add(labelE, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 4;
    fieldE = new JTextField (10);
    p.add(fieldE, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 5;                            
    labelA = new JLabel ("Address:");
    p.add(labelA, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 5;
    fieldA = new JTextField (10);
    p.add(fieldA, c);
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 6;
    aLine2 = new JTextField (10);
    p.add(aLine2, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 7;
    labelW = new JLabel ("Website:");
    p.add(labelW, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 7;
    fieldW = new JTextField (10);
    p.add(fieldW, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 8;
    labelW = new JLabel ("Relationship:");
    p.add(labelW, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 8;
    relationship = new JComboBox(relationshipValues);
    p.add(relationship, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 9;
    buttonS = new JButton("Save:");
    p.add(buttonS, c);

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 10;
    tableDisplay = new JTable();
    p.add(tableDisplay, c);


        // pack the frame for better cross platform support
        f.pack();
        // Make it visible
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(1400,900); // default size is 0,0
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    } // End of Gui Method

    private void UpdateTable() {
        try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM contact";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        tableDisplay.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    }

    catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
                new Driver();

           }
        });
    } // End main Method

       } // End class Driver
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use appropriate [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to lay out the components the way you wish. If you look at the section on `Using a GridBagLayout` you would see that you are using the gridx/gridy constraints incorrectly (they represent a row/column position not pixel location). In addition you would find padding constraints that would give you space between components.

> How can I make the table's rows wider so the data can be displayed properly as well as position the JTable to the top left of screen.

Would that not be row 0, and column 0 if you want to use the GridBagLayout. Read the tutorial for working examples.

You can use the [Table Column Adjuster](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/) to automatically adjust the widths of each column.

Comment: I appreciate your input but that really did not sum it up for me. I understand you are telling me to read the table column adjuster and implement it. And your saying the grids need to be set like, 0 0 or 0 1. not like they are pixels. I changed all the grids and the jtable still does not move as I would expect it to. Can you please elaborate on why this is? I updated my code.

Comment: @NichoDiaz, `I updated my code.` - updated code doesn't help because I can't run the code. I don't have access to your database. Post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) and I might be able to have a quick look, but I an not a GridBagLayout expert. I usually use nested JPanels with different layout managers to achieve my desired layout.